# 1px gap between 2 tables in OUTLOOK 2013

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I have 2 left-aligned tables in my HTML (purpose RESPONSIVE Email HTML).
Outlook is stacking them just for 1 miserable pixel i can not remove.
The 2 images are identical (for testing reasons). But Outlook is inserting 1 pixel on the left border of the 2nd table for any unknown reason.

I give up!. Can anyone figure how to remove it in order to that the 2 tables fit in the parent table and therefore don't stack from up to bottom?

[image: Outlook sample]

HTML Code es here (I attach image from received email in Outlook, as in browsers TABLEs yes do fit correctly):
https://jsfiddle.net/pzamxm9c/#&togetherjs=4x0GFwld1q

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {border-collapse: collapse; margin:0;padding:0;mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
</style>
</head>

<body style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">
<table border="0" width="580" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFCC00">
 <tr>
 <td align="left">
     <table align="left" width="288" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
     <td align="left" bgcolor="#00CC99" style="font-size:1; height:1px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;">
     <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-size:2px;line-height:2px;">    
     <img align="left" src="http://mail.ventura24.es/dialog/elements/eventlayer_left_2.png" alt="Bote: 47 millones" width="289" style=" border: 0px none;" border="0" />     
     </p>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <table align="left" width="288" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
     <td align="left" bgcolor="#00CC99" style="font-size:1; height:1px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;">
     <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-size:2px;line-height:2px;">    
     <img align="left" src="http://mail.ventura24.es/dialog/elements/eventlayer_left_2.png" alt="Bote: 47 millones" width="289" style=" border: 0px none;" border="0" />     
     </p>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Outlook "ghost columns" to contain the side-by-side tables:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td><td align="left">
<![endif]-->
```

This targets all of the Outlooks except Outlook.com.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook will 95% of the times add an extra 1-2px in width of the `<table>` if its side-by-side with another `<table>`. 
The best solution is to wrap them in `<td>`'s.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
*[class].w320 {
    width: 320px !important;
}
*[class].break {
    display: block !important;
}
*[class].break img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">
<table border="0" width="580" class="w320" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFCC00">
  <tr>
    <td class="break w320">
    <table width="290" class="w320" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#00CC99"><img src="http://mail.ventura24.es/dialog/elements/eventlayer_left_2.png" alt="Bote: 47 millones" width="289" border="0" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="break w320">
    <table width="290" class="w320" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#00CC99"><img src="http://mail.ventura24.es/dialog/elements/eventlayer_left_2.png" alt="Bote: 47 millones" width="289" border="0"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good Point. worked almost. Wrapping the tables in TD did the work. HOWEVER this prevented the 2 images to stack top to bottom in Android and other devices. 

@Rasmus, Finally, I added to your answer conditional comments to wrap each table in Outlook and leave the rest of devices with both TABLEs as siblings. That did the trick. I post final code below. 
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Its easy to make them stack on mobile devices, you just need some media queries. I will add the complete solution for you soon :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
  <td align="left">
    <table align="left" width="290" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:1; height:1px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"><p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"> <img align="left" src="http://mail.ventura24.es/dialog/elements/eventlayer_left_2.png" alt="Bote: 47 millones" width="290" style=" border: 0px none;" border="0" /> </p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </td>
    <![endif]--> 

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <td align="left">
    <![endif]-->      
    <table align="left" width="290" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:1; height:1px;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"><p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"> <img align="left" src="http://mail.ventura24.es/dialog/elements/eventlayer_left_2.png" alt="Bote: 47 millones" width="290" style=" border: 0px none;" border="0" /> </p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>        
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not giving any space between the two tables:

```
</table><table align="left" width="288" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Or:

```
</table><!--
--><table align="left" width="288" height="329" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```